# Change and keep active class in navigation menu, on click and refresh

Tags: javascript, onclick, navigation, local-storage

I am trying to create a navigation menu using css and js. I have styled the necessary classes, and nav works with js animation, however I am having a problem changing the class of li to active onclick by the user, and saving this in local storage so that it remains when the page refreshes.

This is the code that I have now:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wfpti

Javascript:

```
var foundActive = false, activeElement, linePosition = 0, menuLine = $("#navmenu #menu-line"), lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

$("#navmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    activeElement = $(this);
    foundActive = true;
}
});
```

Html:

```
<div id='navmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='link1.php'>link1</a></li>
   <li><a href='link2.php'>link2</a></li>
   <li><a href='link3.php'>link3</a></li>
   <li><a href='link4.php'>link4</a></li>
   <li><a href='link5.php'>link5</a></li>
   <li><a href='link6.php'>link6</a></li>
   <li><a href='link7.php'>link7</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve is that when I press, for example, "link3" is that it goes to link3.php, and the navigation menu then shows link3 as the active class link, while removing the previous active class for link1.

Comment: Just saying you have a problem is not particularly helpful, what exactly is the problem/does not work, also please reduce your code snippet to the relevant part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to add class on click event this function will stop your active links. this may works for you. if you want to add active class after refreshing a page then store it to javascript cookies.

```
    $("#navmenu > ul > li").click(function() 
    {
            $(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function()
            {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
            $(this).addClass('active');
            defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();
            defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
            menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
            menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
    });
```

Comment: put above code after this $("#navmenu > ul > li").each(); event.

Comment: Thank you the proposed solution. It works brilliantly. Thanks.